# running code repeatedly in background on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I'm making an alarm clock-like app. The user should be notified with a vibration and a sound every 10-60 seconds over a period of about 30 minutes. What is the best approach for this? It's easy enough doing it in the foreground, but how can i continue to run scheduled code in the background? I could use local notifications, but the user doesn't receive them when in "do not disturb" mode.

Comment: It's worth noting that if your app doesn't meet the specific categories which allow unlimited background time, you can only request 10 minutes after backgrounding the app. Local notifications are the usual way this would be implemented (e.g. the native Reminders app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review the documentation about background execution: [Background Execution and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20). There are multiple ways of consistently running code in the background, but your app has to meet certain guidelines to use them--in your case, I don't think your app neatly falls into any of the categories Apple describes in [Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24). There's always the possibility the submission reviews could approve your app anyway.

To avoid potential app rejection, you should implement your app using local notifications, and include a warning in your app that users should disable "Do Not Disturb" for it to function correctly. Unfortunately, there isn't a way for users to exclude apps from DND, nor is there a public API to manipulate DND.