# iOS: Repeated task only when APP is active (No background)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I have found several [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181130/running-code-repeatedly-in-background-on-ios) asking how to run background tasks. This is fine. I get it. There is a [guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24) from Apple and can be done only for certain types of Apps.

My use case here is the following: **I want to update the contact list of a chat App only when the APP is in foreground**. Hence I can start/pause/resume when the App goes respectively in the following states: didBegan, didEnterBackground, didResumeFromBackground.

**How can I achieve this using GCD?**

In other words, how can I schedule an asynchrounous task in a repeated way and to be called only every so often (say every 0.5 seconds)? Is there a good implementation using NSOperationQueue?

EDIT 2: Tasks I want to perform:

1: GET from a webservice API a JSON data object containing information on the contacts (online status, device, lastseen at)

2: GET from a webservice API a JSON data object containing messages to the user

EDIT: NSOperation documentation defines an operation as something that can be used only as "single shot", hence creating a recursive operation is probably not the best way to solve this.

Comment: Huh? A recursive operation? You can create an operation with a block, and it behaves exactly the same as a dispatch queue.

Comment: @LeoNatan I see your point in the comments. I will try your approach. So basically NSTimer objects executes only when the App is in foreground and not in background and have their own internal resume/suspend method correct?

Comment: Yes. When the app goes to background, timers are suspended. When it returns to foreground, the timers are resumed, and any timer that is due will fire. One caveat to this is a case where your app may wake up in the background (from, say, a push). While the app is running, timers also run, in the background.

Comment: @LeonNatan Thanks. Not the same but related: what happens to a dispatch queue when the APP enters background? Is the queue suspended and then resumed? And if not, what happens if an task has not reached the block? In other words, if I call "dispatch_async(server_queue, ^{_block_})" will the _block_ always be reached?

Comment: The entire app is suspended, so yes, the dispatch queues and operation queues are all suspended. If you have queued a task or an operation, it will fire once the system has resumed (either when app goes to foreground or if it resumes running in the background).

Comment: @LeoNatan sorry for the lame PS, but I have tried to create a NSOperation starting from a NSTimer object but is not possible. Should I create some intermediate object? Is there a good example I could follow? Thanks a lot and sorry again.

Comment: See my answer with code examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code on how to achieve this with a timer and both GCD and an operation queue.

```
NSOperationQueue* queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]; //Make serial.
//dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL); //Serial queue.
```

Gentlemen, start your timers:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:appDelegate selector:@selector(timerTicked:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; //Start a timer with 0 so it ticks immediately.
```

Now in the method:

```
- (void)timerTicked:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSLog(@"Timer ticked!");
    void (^block)() = ^{
        //Do what you need here.

        //Start a new timer.
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:appDelegate selector:@selector(timerTicked:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    };

    [queue addOperationWithBlock:block];
    //dispatch_async(queue, block);
}
```

I use the app delegate because timers retain the target object, so I don't want to have it in a view controller. You can schedule the next timer either right after timer tick or after the operation/task has completed, which is what I prefer to do.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the repeated questions and comments :-). Wish I could give +5 upvotes as it is extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSTimer to schedule a timer that fires every .5 seconds.  It could add your NSOperation to an NSOperationQueue.  You might want to make a special queue with a max concurrency of 1, so it will only run one of your things at a time.  You might also want to cancel all previous operations when adding a new one, just in case things start to 'pile up'.  I don't know what your specific task is so it's hard to be more precise.

Comment: Fantastic. This sounds excellent. I will try it straight away.

Comment: @mm24 A word on timers. If you set the timer as repeating, an ill effect may occur after coming from background, where the timer may fire many times (the number of times it would have fired had the it had the opportunity to run). Better approach is to schedule the timer as not repeating and scheduling a new one once the old one's handler finishes its task.

Comment: @jsd I added a specifc use case to the answer